# Native Drag and Drop check for dropped item's id

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, native

I would like to check to see if an item with id === itemId is dropped on a droppable element, using native Drag and Drop.

```
function dragDrop(itemId){        

    var droppable = document.querySelector('#droppableElement');

    addEvent(droppable, 'drop', function(e){
        if (e.preventDefault){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        // How do I check that the id of the dropped item === itemId    
        if (e.dataTransfer.getData('id') === itemId){ 
            alert('Successfuly dropped item with id = ' itemId + '.');
        }
    });
}

draggableItem = document.querySelector('#draggable');
dragDrop(draggableItem);
```

The comment is where I need help. This link was my point of departure.
http://html5doctor.com/native-drag-and-drop

Comment: I dont even get 'dataTransfer' attributes on my drop event. :-(

Answer (score 2):

When the `ondragstart` event is fired, you should set the dataTransfer's data to the id of the element that you're transferring. So, your code would be:

```
function dragDrop(itemId){        

    var droppable = document.querySelector('#droppableElement');
    addEvent(droppable, 'drop', function(e){
        if (e.preventDefault){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (e.dataTransfer.getData('id') == itemId){ 
            alert('Successfuly dropped item with id = ' itemId + '.');
        }
    });
}

draggableItem = document.querySelector('#draggable');
addEvent(draggableItem, "dragstart", function(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('id', this.id);
});
dragDrop(draggableItem.id);
```

Sources: [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/native-drag-and-drop/)